# Java game logic, check if object is placed in one of possible positions

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I am developing a 2D java game, where use has to place certain objects (such as boxes, containers etc) in proper places.

- each object, got its destination [X,Y] where player should place them.

But the problem is, when there is more than one object of the same type, it should be up to player to decide in which position he wants to place it (instead of guessing)

Now I am wondering how to create proper logic to handle this issue, I am loading all level data from XML file, my idea was:

- while loading level from XML, add all objects to the array list
- after loading all objects, iterate through this list, and sort all objects into new array lists, one per object type (like box, container) so later, I can iterate through those lists and check object is currently placed in any possible position.

Though I am still not sure, some help would be appreciate.

Edit: following answer from @EZSlaver I came to this:

```
private HashMap<ObjectType, ArrayList<GameObject>> map = new HashMap<ObjectType, ArrayList<GameObject>>();

public void addObjekt(GameObject objekt)
{
    if (map.containsKey(objekt.getType()))
    {
        map.get(ObjectType.TYPE_BOX).add(objekt);
    }
    else
    {
        ArrayList<GameObject> arrayOfObjects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
        arrayOfObjects.add(objekt);

        map.put(objekt.getType(), arrayOfObjects);
    }       
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Test();
}

private enum ObjectType
{
    TYPE_BOX,
    TYPE_CONTAINER
}

/**
 * Subclass of GameObject, box (name of game object) representation
 */
public class Box extends GameObject
{
    public Box(float destX, float destY)
    {
        super(ObjectType.TYPE_BOX, destX, destY);
    }
}

/**
 * Subclass of GameObject, Container (name of game object) representation
 */
public class Container extends GameObject
{
    public Container(float destX, float destY)
    {
        super(ObjectType.TYPE_CONTAINER, destX, destY);
    }
}

/**
 * Base type class, any object representation
 */
public class GameObject
{
    private ObjectType Type;
    private float destX;
    private float destY;

    public GameObject(ObjectType type, float destX, float destY)
    {
        super();
        Type = type;
        this.destX = destX;
        this.destY = destY;
    }

    public ObjectType getType()
    {
        return Type;
    }

    public float getDestX()
    {
        return destX;
    }

    public float getDestY()
    {
        return destY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Comment: Strictly for this issue, I have no code yet, I am trying to figure out proper strategy, generally In my game I have various "objectives" such as move vehicle to position, destroy bricks using certain vehicle, load objects on the vehicle, and global class which is managing those objectives. Now I am trying to make objectives where player need to place certain object in its destination X, Y but as explained problem is that player should be allowed to place it any possible position (for example if there is more than one object of this type, with different destination)

Comment: Your question is too broad and you haven't started implementing it. I would suggest you present your way of implemneting it (code) and then it would be easier for us to help you

Comment: Posted code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following data structures (I come from C#, so mind the syntactic changes):

```
public enum GameObjectType { Vehicle, Brick, ... };

public class GameObject
{
    GameObjectType Type;
    string Name;
    long ID; // I don't know if you need one
    Point Location;

    ...
}

public GameObject[,] Board;

Dictionary<GameObjectType, List<GameObject>> GameObjectsByType; // A mapping of all game objects by their type.
```

You can replace the type of the `Board` to something else that represents a general slot in the board, and contains a reference to objects on the slot.

From here, upon loading the board, add all items to the map-object `GameObjectsByType`, and manage it in the future.

Comment: Thank you for an asnwer, one question though, following line: 

Dictionary<GameObjectType, List<GameObject>> GameObjectsByType;

is that array of arryas?

Comment: It is a map object from the enum-type `GameObjectType` to an array (or a length-changing array) of `GameObject`s. In Java I believe it's called `Map`.

Comment: Thanks, edited my question and created it way you posted, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with the same list of "possible places" for all objects of the same type, then when an object is placed at [X,Y] -- remove that [X,Y] from the lists of remaining "unplaced" objects.